# Does the presence of Giant Cave Spider Silk always indicate the presence of Giant Cave Spiders?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

So, I've decided that I want to breach the first level cavern I've found. I noticed that there are a significant number of Giant Cave Spider Silk covering the floor of the cavern. However, looking in the <kbd>u</kbd>nits menu, I don't see any Giant Cave Spider.

Does this mean that there are no Giant Cave Spiders in the cavern? And would the silk regenerate if there indeed isn't one?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

A Giant Cave Spider **may or may not be on the map** upon embark, or worse, it may be lying in wait to ambush your dwarves, invisible until they get too close, but the presence of their silk is only a dead giveaway that there are *some* **available** to your map.

Giant Cave Spider silk will not regenerate without a live Giant Cave Spider to spew it.

Comment: Does _map_ in this context mean world map, or embark map?

Comment: @antipattern embark map -- items don't exist on the world map.

Comment: Okay- I don't understand the meaning of _available_ then. Do you want to say that they could possibly spawn in the embark? From what you wrote before, I understand there can be webbing, but that does not imply that there is a spider lurking somewhere...

Comment: @antipattern That's exactly it -- if there is Giant Cave Spider webbing *on the map*, it is a possibility for it to re-enter your map later, even if its not currently there.